# IE 11 navigates to the same page on link click in ASP .NET MVC application

Tags: html, asp.net-mvc, internet-explorer

I have the following html in my application:

```
<ul>
    <li><a href="/link">Link 1</a></li>
    <a href="/link">Link 2</a>
</ul>
```

The problem is that `Link 1` is not working in `IE`. `Link 2` does, but `Link 2` is directly in `ul` element which is wrong. When I click `Link 1` in `IE` I get the same page (`https://localhost:44302` in my case) and the console output is:

```
HTML1300: Navigation occurred.
File: link

HTML1300: Navigation occurred.
File: localhost:44302
```

Browser seams to redirect back to the original page and I have no idea why. When I click `Link 2` (in `IE`) i get the page I requested and the console says:

```
HTML1300: Navigation occurred.
File: link
```

**What could be the possible reasons?**

Comment: Can you show us what your controller looks like? It sounds like the site is doing a redirect when you navigate to link1.

Comment: @JLRishe, I've added some changes to the question to make it more clear and relevant to my issue. The thing is that both of the links point to the same action.